# How to change colour of row when is selected in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

i follow [this example](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/repeater/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.repeater.OIRPage&source=OIRPage.java) but I want to change it. I want to select row when you click wherever on the certain row not just to some value so I add `AjaxEventBehavior`. Problem is that player is selected but colour of row is still same. What is wrong ?

```
listItem.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void onEvent(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        selectedPlayer = player;
        HighlitableDataItem<Player> hitem = (HighlitableDataItem<Player>) listItem;
        hitem.toggleHighlite();
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to add your `hitem` to the `target` to update it throw AJAx

Comment: thx it works. change this comment to answer to accept it

Comment: Some aditional info is: if you need to repaint a component (mostly containers) it is advisable to set its output markup id to true (`component.setOutputMarkupId(true)`) so that wicket is able to find the component through ajax. When repainting wicket will _pull_ the data from the Models used by the component and refresh the component's data/presentation.

Comment: I'd advise to perform this kind of logic in (pure or jquery) javascript. Using Ajax to just style an HTML element can be kind of an overkill, and you can experience annoying lags when the server is at critical load levels or a client's connection is too slow. That said, if you're performing some logic that's needed for server side purposes (such as keeping track of the selected element) I would agree with using Ajax.

Comment: please change your comment too answer. I want close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jordeu already pointed out in his comment, you've got to add `hitem` to the `AjaxRequestTarget`:

```
target.addComponent(hitem);
```

Adding the component to the `AjaxRequestTarget` will send back to the XML response the markup of the component, with all the changes you've possibily made to it server-side, and with updated models (this is useful for dynamic models). Remember to invoke `setOutputMarkupId(true)` on the components you want to add to the request target. Wicket needs the markup id (HTML `id` attribute) to know where in the DOM to replace the markup sent in the XML response. Or, in words of the [javadoc](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.html):

> A component whose markup needs to be updated should be added to this
>   target via AjaxRequestTarget#addComponent(Component) method. Its body
>   will be rendered and added to the envelope when the target is
>   processed, and refreshed on the client side when the ajax response is
>   received.
>
> It is important that the component whose markup needs to be updated
>   contains an id attribute in the generated markup that is equal to the
>   value retrieved from Component#getMarkupId(). This can be accomplished
>   by either setting the id attribute in the html template, or using an
>   attribute modifier that will add the attribute with value
>   Component#getMarkupId() to the tag ( such as MarkupIdSetter )

Also, take into account that using Ajax to just style an element can be kind of an overkill. If no server interaction is required, you might consider styling the element client-side with Javascript/jQuery if available.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to render javaScript into your table. Doing so you **avoid roundtrips to the server**, which would be overkill in this simple just-for-styling case.

You acheive it with overriding DataTable#newRowItem and adding AttributeAppender to the RowItem :

```
//override this method of the DataTable class
@Override
protected Item<T> newRowItem(String id, int index, final IModel<T> model) {

    Item<T> rowItem = new Item<T>(id, index, model);
    item.add(new AttributeAppender("onclick", "$(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected')",
            " "));

    return rowItem;

}
```

Define your selection styling under 'selected' selector in your css stylesheet.